# for:each and for:item directives should be associated together. I dont know what it means

Tags: lightning-web-components

this is my playground 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/MfZhlKyx-/edit

this is my page I'm trying to render

```html
<div class="row">

    <template if:true={isMobileTemplate}>

      <template for:each{mobiles} for:item={mobile}>
        <div class="column">
          <div class="card" key={mobile.itemid}>
            {mobile.title}
            {mobile.rating}
            {mobile.price}
            {mobile.size}
            {mobile.speed}
            {mobile.ram}
          </div>
        </div>
      </template>
    </template>

    <template if:true={isShirtTemplate}>
      <template for:each{shirts} for:item={shirt}>
        <div class="column">
          <div class="card" key={shird.id}>
            {shirt.title}
            {shirt.rating}
            {shirt.price}
            {shirt.size}
            {shirt.color}
          </div>
        </div>
      </template>
    </template>
    <template if:true={isNoTemplate}>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to render a JS object based on conditional rendering. I don't understand where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot an equals sign:

```
for:each={mobiles}
```

Just a simple typo.

Also, for:item should use quotes:

```
for:item="mobile"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<div if:true={condition}>
```

instead of nested templates.

Comment: A big thanks. Its working